# cabal install hsdev fails on win32-notify-0.3.0.1

Tags: haskell, sublimetext3, haskell-stack, hsdev

I'm trying to install hsdev and it is failing on `win32-notify-0.3.0.1`

```
Failed to install Win32-notify-0.3.0.1
Build log ( C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\ghc-8.2.1\Win32-notify-0.3.0.1-4SkPzVSpsVh3tD4JgoFSXp.log ):
Preprocessing library for Win32-notify-0.3.0.1..
Building library for Win32-notify-0.3.0.1..
[1 of 2] Compiling System.Win32.FileNotify ( dist\build\System\Win32\FileNotify.hs, dist\build\System\Win32\FileNotify.o )

src\System\Win32\FileNotify.hsc:29:9: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence `fILE_LIST_DIRECTORY'
    It could refer to either `System.Win32.File.fILE_LIST_DIRECTORY',
                             imported from `System.Win32.File' at src\System\Win32\FileNotify.hsc:13:1-24
                          or `System.Win32.FileNotify.fILE_LIST_DIRECTORY',
                             defined at src\System\Win32\FileNotify.hsc:66:1
   |
29 |         fILE_LIST_DIRECTORY -- Access mode
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-11528\Win32-notify-0.3.0.1'
Installed unix-compat-0.4.3.1
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
Win32-notify-0.3.0.1-4SkPzVSpsVh3tD4JgoFSXp failed during the building phase.
The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
fsnotify-0.2.1.1-JyIc8LmykhYJl0khTEfcky depends on fsnotify-0.2.1.1 which
failed to install.
```

This is the first time that I have tried to use `cabal` so any help with debugging this would be appreciated.

Additionally the reason I'm trying to install this is for the SublimeHaskell, it is saying that hsdev cannot be found (I installed haskell via the Haskell-Platform).

Comment: The `Win32-notify` package is just broken. It places no upper bound on `Win32`, and that package has at some point begun to export the symbol `fILE_LIST_DIRECTORY`. (I don't see how `hsdev` could build on any recent GHC without explicitly giving a specific version of `Win32` to use, so arguably it is broken as well). As far as building broken packages goes: best you can do is contact the maintainer, and in the meantime, download the source and fix it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in recent versions of `Win32-notify`:

https://github.com/haskell-fswatch/win32-notify/commit/0b14cf7065adf80928ab98d7e1a3abd5f992d0c3